# How to see total sales of one group in Magento and make and group moderator

Tags: php, mysql, magento

So basically I need to figure out how to get sales report of a group of customers, also I need a "group moderator" role.
Let's say I have groups "Alpha", "Beta" and "Gamma", and three group moderators:

- I need to make it so every moderator is assigned to one group, and it can add/remove users only to/from the group that he moderates
- I need to make it so every group has it's sales report with total sales summed up

Is this possible in Magento backend, or any kind of solution that returns this results?

Comment: Is it customer  group??

Comment: Yup, I need to make 3 customer groups, and those groups can be edited by appointed moderator (add/remove users), and moderators can only view/edit their own group, and root admin adds them.

Comment: It is something like Azuwa B2b solution... it has Admin, Manager, Customers... etc.